# Cómo sumarle un día a la fecha que se recibe de un servicio y colocarla en mat datepicker en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

Tengo la siguiente tabla que se llena con un servicio  y en el campo FECHA REGISTRO se muestra con mat datepicker , pero al usar el componente se muestra la fecha con un día menos, entonces lo que quiero es que a la fecha que recibo le sume un día, para que el componente muestre la fecha correcta

html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idControl }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ESTADO</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-select [(value)]="element.cveEstado" (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)"
          [disabled]="!element.editar">
          
          <mat-option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado" [ngClass]="{
              'text-red': estatus.cveEstado == 'ERR',
              'text-blue': estatus.cveEstado == 'INP'
            }">
            {{ estatus.descripcion }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>COMENTARIO</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [value]="element.comentario" (keyup)="changeValue($event.target, element)"
          [disabled]="!element.editar" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HORA</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [value]="element.horaInicio" (keyup)="changeValueHora($event.target, element)"
          [disabled]="!element.editar" type="time" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRegistro">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>FECHAREGISTRO</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="element.fechaRegistro">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="element.fechaRegistro"
          (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value, element)" [disabled]="!element.editar" />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="botonSave">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>GUARDAR</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
      <button mat-button (click)="guardar(element)">Guardar</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Control } from './Control';
import { ControlService } from './control.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Estado } from './Estado.ts';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { UntypedFormBuilder, UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-angular-material';
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'idControl',
    'cveEstado',
    'comentario',
    'horaInicio',
    'fechaRegistro',
    'botonSave',
  ];
  estadoModel: Estado[] = [];
  control: Control[] = [];
  controlModel: Control = new Control();
  estadoSeleccionado: any;
  idSeleccionado: string = '';
  comentIngresado: string = '';
  horaIngresada: string ='';
  fechaIngresada: any;
  dataModel: any[] = [];
  horaInvalida = true;

  constructor(
    private controlService: ControlService,
    private dataAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>
  ) {
    this.dataAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerLista();
    this.obtenerListaEstados();
  }

  //obtiene la lista del servicio
  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
      this.control = response.data;
      console.log("PRUEBA " ,response.data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
    });
  }

  //obtiene la lista de estados para el select
  private obtenerListaEstados() {
    this.controlService.obtenerEstados().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log("PRUEBA  estados" ,response.data);
      this.estadoModel = response.data;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la cve del estado que se selecciona y su id
  cambiarEstado(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.estadoSeleccionado = valor;
    this.idSeleccionado = row.idControl;

    console.log(' ID SELECC ' + this.idSeleccionado);
    console.log(' ESTADO SELECC ' + this.estadoSeleccionado);
  }

  //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input coment  y el id
  changeValue(e: any, row: any) {
    this.comentIngresado = e.value;
    console.log(' INPUT COMENT  ' + this.comentIngresado);
  }

 //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input hora, y el id
 changeValueHora(e: any, row: any) {
  this.horaIngresada = e.value;
  console.log(' INPUT HORA   ' +this.horaIngresada);
  this.validarHora();
}

validarHora() {
  console.log(' ENTRA A VALIDAR HORA');
  const regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$");
  this.horaInvalida = !regex.test(this.horaIngresada);
  console.log('HORA '  + this.horaInvalida);
}


  //OBTIENE EL VALOR DE LA FECHA SELECCIONADA
  onDateChange(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.fechaIngresada = valor;
    console.log('FECHA SELECC  ' + this.fechaIngresada);
  }

  //funcion para darle formato a la fecha internamente
  formatDateToString(date: Date): string {
    if (date) {
      const format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
      const locale = 'en-US';
      return formatDate(date, format, locale);
    }
    return '';
  }

  guardar(element: any) {
    if (element.editar) {
      console.log(`Desactivado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = false;

      if (this.comentIngresado == '') {
        alert('No se han modificado campos');
      } else {
        console.log(' ENTRA ELSE  ');
        this.controlModel.cveEstado = this.estadoSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.comentario = this.comentIngresado;
        this.controlModel.idControl = this.idSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.fechaRegistro = this.formatDateToString(
          this.fechaIngresada
        );

        console.log('prueba fecha final  ' + this.controlModel.fechaRegistro);
        this.controlService
          .updateCampo(this.controlModel)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.controlModel = data;
            this.comentIngresado = '';
            this.estadoSeleccionado = '';
            this.fechaIngresada = '';

            alert('Agregado correctamente');
          });
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Activado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = true;
    }
  }
}
```

la fecha que recibo del servicio esta asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al mostrarse en el mat datepicker la muestra asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cómo puedo solucionar este problema para mostrar la fecha correcta?

Comment: El problema no este y la solución tampoco lo es, checa los usos horarios que estás utilizando. Puede ser que estes registrando los datos en UTC, mientras que al usar `dataAdapter` te regrese la hora con el huso horario de México (UTC -6)

Comment: @René y como veo los horario que se estan utilizando? el campo element.fechaRegistro sin agregar el Matdatepicker, se muestra en este formato -- >    2023-05-26 07:21:00

Comment: y cuando seleccionas una fecha del Datepicker, se ve de este formato,  --- > Thu May 25 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central)

Comment: MatDatePicker solamente funciona para fechas, Angular no tiene algo para manejar las horas (TimePicker), desde hace 6 años que abrieron el issue [feat(datepicker): add support for choosing time #5648](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5648) en el repositorio de GitHub pidiendo un Time Picker pero parece que no es su prioridad. Tal vez usando moment o alguna otra librería que maneje fecha y horas, si lo quieres usar junto al MatDatePicker hay librerías que se encargan de eso pero es prueba y error, varias no soportan el locale o simplemente ya son obsoletas.

Comment: Y será que por eso al usar el datepicker le quite un día? O como puedo hacerle para que a la fecha que recibo le quite la hora, y ya que tenga sólo la fecha se muestre en el calendario?

Comment: Parece que hace poco salió [Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) que te podría servir para manejar solamente fechas sin horas. Que el datepicker le quite un día será por la zona horaria. Hay otra forma de establecer el locale, usando i18n y sus respectivos pipes que convierten fechas, horas, monedas, etc a como se usan en cada lugar [LOCALE_ID](https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID)